# ActiveRecord connection establishing, but why is it not connected

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm in the process of updating ActiveRecord on my ruby suite (a much needed upgrade) and I'm running into an issue with the database connections.  It doesn't seem to fail on the ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection call, however when I puts the connected? method it returns false.  I've included the hash i'm passing into the establish_connection method (subbing out the url, username, and password that I've verified work) and my connected? call

```
puts "establishing connection to #{config[env]}"
@db_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config[env])
puts "database connected? #{@db_connection.connected?}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
establishing connection to {"adapter"=>"jdbc", "driver"=>"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "url"=>"my_url","username"=>"my_username", "password"=>"my_password"}

database connected? false
```

EDIT: connect method

```
  def connect(env)
    begin
    config = YAML.load_file("features/config/servers.yml")
    rescue
      puts "cannot load config/servers.yml"
    end
    puts "establishing connection to #{config[env]}"
    @db_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config[env])
    puts @db_connection.connected?
    puts "connected to #{config[env]}"
  end
```

Database YML

```
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_ip_address)(PORT=host_port_number))(CONNECT_DATA=(UR=A)(SERVICE_NAME=database_name)))
  username: my_username
  password: My_Password
```

Comment: where your `database` on `config[env]`?

Comment: @Monk_Code in a servers.yml file... See updates for entire connect method

Comment: i mean `database` name for connect?

Comment: Yes. What Monk_Code means is usually you have a `database` element in your DB config file (server.yml I guess in your case) that indicates the specific database to connect to. Yours doesn't seem to have this so far as we can see. I

Comment: @Monk_Code I've attached a database record from my servers.yml file. It looks like I do not have a database listed, but the server name is in the url.  See attached

Comment: @MattWestlake I've never connected in that exact manner (using the JDBC driver and that form of URL path), but I still don't see any kind of database element in the yml, save for the `SERVICE_NAME=database_name`. Is `SERVICE_NAME` used to indicate the name of the db to connect to?

Comment: @Teeg Yes, that is the name of the database

Comment: @MattWestlake Ok, hmm. Does it make a difference if you explicitly add `database: database_name` as another element of the YML? If not, I'm afraid I don't think I can help. Your YML looks valid to me (other than the parts I'm not familiar with). Sorry.:(